# Definition relating to geometry

Tags: meaning, adjectives

What word in geometry that describes angles has a meaning outside geometry that means strange or odd ?

Comment: I learned at school that there are three types of angles: *acute, obtuse* and *reflex*. None of those means "strange or odd". Perhaps those types have other names too.

Comment: I think OP may be confusing ***obtuse*** with ***abstruse***?

Comment: How about 'skew'? If you win something with this, share the winnings!

Answer (score 1):

Eccentricity is a parameter in [mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_%28mathematics%29) that is associated with every conic section (ellipse, parabola, hyperbola). It means the state of being strange or unusual in [English](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/eccentricity).

Comment: Yes, but how is that related to angles?

Comment: @Josh, in geometry is more related to [curves than angles](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentricity_(mathematics)), and it would be good if Jasper included some geometric sections of the term in the body of his answer, but I do believe he's solved this puzzle. Both definitions derive from *deviation*. +1.